# OpenCL on Linux with integrated intel graphic chip

Tags: linux, graphics, opencl, gpu, intel

I would like to use `OpenCL` on debian 8. I read [on this page](http://streamcomputing.eu/blog/2011-12-29/opencl-hardware-support/) that Intel's GPUs are not supported on linux. (The article is from 2011, so I hope it is out of date.) I already installed OpenCL nontheless and can run compile and run the code found [here](https://www.fixstars.com/en/opencl/book/OpenCLProgrammingBook/first-opencl-program/).

As to my hardware. 
My processor is `Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4500 CPU @ 1.80GHz`

`lspci | grep VGA` outputs

`00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)`

So to clearify: I want to know, if it is possible to utilize the Graphics chip on this setup. I hope the information I provided is enough.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Beignet](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/Beignet/), an open source implementation of OpenCL for Intel GPUs that is lead by Intel themselves. On Debian you can install this via `apt-get`:

```
apt-get install beignet
```

Comment: Thanks, I will most definitely try that later.

Comment: Is the code the same regardless if I use opencl or beignet?

Comment: Beignet is just an implementation of OpenCL so yes, just write regular OpenCL code.

Comment: I tried installing `beignet` and it seems to work fine. Although it already compiled the code before I installed it. Can you tell me how to make sure it's really using the graphics chip? This may be very obvious, but I'm new to OpenCL.
I also just realised, that the number of platforms switched from 2 to 3 after installing beignet. So it must have done something. I don't know what though.

Comment: Given a `cl_device_id` object, you can get the name of the device like this: `char name[256]; clGetDeviceInfo(device_id, CL_DEVICE_NAME, 256, name, NULL); printf("Device name: %s\n", name);`

Comment: You can view a list of available platforms and devices by running the `clinfo` command (`apt-get install clinfo`).

Comment: the device name is the Intel(R) Core... printed in the original question. how come the number of devices is 3 though?

Comment: You have multiple OpenCL platforms/devices available. Run `clinfo` (see previous comment) to see the full list of platforms and devices.

Comment: It's true. It shows several OpenCL platforms. Is that a problem? Should I remove any or do I need all of them?

Comment: That's not a problem, this is how OpenCL works. You can have many OpenCL devices available, and your code will have to pick which one(s) it needs to use.

Comment: Do I have to choose the right one or does the code do that on its own?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98421/discussion-between-ben-and-jprice).

Comment: beignet seems no longer supported: last release is from 2017. use intel's Neo driver instead: https://github.com/intel/compute-runtime#installation-options

Answer (score 2):

As of 2021 Intel's Neo driver seems to be the only actively supported solution: https://github.com/intel/compute-runtime

([beignet's repo](https://github.com/intel/beignet) is read-only now and README states that the project is discontinued)

Answer (score 1):

Update to @jprice's answer.

In Debian Bullseye:

```
apt install beignet-opencl-icd
apt install clinfo
```

and it works well on a Macmini6,1:

```
root@mini1:~$ clinfo 
Number of platforms                               1
  Platform Name                                   Intel Gen OCL Driver
  Platform Vendor                                 Intel
  Platform Version                                OpenCL 2.0 beignet 1.3
  Platform Profile                                FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Extensions                             cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_3d_image_writes cl_khr_image2d_from_buffer cl_khr_depth_images cl_khr_spir cl_khr_icd cl_intel_accelerator cl_intel_subgroups cl_intel_subgroups_short
  Platform Extensions function suffix             Intel

  Platform Name                                   Intel Gen OCL Driver
Number of devices                                 1
  Device Name                                     Intel(R) HD Graphics IvyBridge M GT2
  Device Vendor                                   Intel
  Device Vendor ID                                0x8086
  Device Version                                  OpenCL 1.2 beignet 1.3
  Driver Version                                  1.3
  Device OpenCL C Version                         OpenCL C 1.2 beignet 1.3
  Device Type                                     GPU
  Device Profile                                  FULL_PROFILE
  Device Available                                Yes
  Compiler Available                              Yes
  Linker Available                                Yes
  Max compute units                               16
  Max clock frequency                             1000MHz
  Device Partition                                (core)
    Max number of sub-devices                     1
    Supported partition types                     None, None, None
    Supported affinity domains                    (n/a)
  Max work item dimensions                        3
  Max work item sizes                             512x512x512
  Max work group size                             512
  Preferred work group size multiple (kernel)     16
  Preferred / native vector sizes                 
    char                                                16 / 8       
    short                                                8 / 8       
    int                                                  4 / 4       
    long                                                 2 / 2       
    half                                                 0 / 8        (n/a)
    float                                                4 / 4       
    double                                               0 / 2        (n/a)
  Half-precision Floating-point support           (n/a)
  Single-precision Floating-point support         (core)
    Denormals                                     No
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 No
    Round to infinity                             No
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               No
    Support is emulated in software               No
    Correctly-rounded divide and sqrt operations  No
  Double-precision Floating-point support         (n/a)
  Address bits                                    32, Little-Endian
  Global memory size                              2147483648 (2GiB)
  Error Correction support                        No
  Max memory allocation                           1610612736 (1.5GiB)
  Unified memory for Host and Device              Yes
  Minimum alignment for any data type             128 bytes
  Alignment of base address                       1024 bits (128 bytes)
  Global Memory cache type                        Read/Write
  Global Memory cache size                        8192 (8KiB)
  Global Memory cache line size                   64 bytes
  Image support                                   Yes
    Max number of samplers per kernel             16
    Max size for 1D images from buffer            65536 pixels
    Max 1D or 2D image array size                 2048 images
    Base address alignment for 2D image buffers   4096 bytes
    Pitch alignment for 2D image buffers          1 pixels
    Max 2D image size                             8192x8192 pixels
    Max 3D image size                             8192x8192x2048 pixels
    Max number of read image args                 128
    Max number of write image args                8
  Local memory type                               Local
  Local memory size                               65536 (64KiB)
  Max number of constant args                     8
  Max constant buffer size                        134217728 (128MiB)
  Max size of kernel argument                     1024
  Queue properties                                
    Out-of-order execution                        No
    Profiling                                     Yes
  Prefer user sync for interop                    Yes
  Profiling timer resolution                      80ns
  Execution capabilities                          
    Run OpenCL kernels                            Yes
    Run native kernels                            Yes
    SPIR versions                                 1.2
  printf() buffer size                            1048576 (1024KiB)
  Built-in kernels                                __cl_copy_region_align4;__cl_copy_region_align16;__cl_cpy_region_unalign_same_offset;__cl_copy_region_unalign_dst_offset;__cl_copy_region_unalign_src_offset;__cl_copy_buffer_rect;__cl_copy_image_1d_to_1d;__cl_copy_image_2d_to_2d;__cl_copy_image_3d_to_2d;__cl_copy_image_2d_to_3d;__cl_copy_image_3d_to_3d;__cl_copy_image_2d_to_buffer;__cl_copy_image_3d_to_buffer;__cl_copy_buffer_to_image_2d;__cl_copy_buffer_to_image_3d;__cl_fill_region_unalign;__cl_fill_region_align2;__cl_fill_region_align4;__cl_fill_region_align8_2;__cl_fill_region_align8_4;__cl_fill_region_align8_8;__cl_fill_region_align8_16;__cl_fill_region_align128;__cl_fill_image_1d;__cl_fill_image_1d_array;__cl_fill_image_2d;__cl_fill_image_2d_array;__cl_fill_image_3d;block_motion_estimate_intel;
  Device Extensions                               cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_3d_image_writes cl_khr_image2d_from_buffer cl_khr_depth_images cl_khr_spir cl_khr_icd cl_intel_accelerator cl_intel_subgroups cl_intel_subgroups_short cl_intel_motion_estimation

NULL platform behavior
  clGetPlatformInfo(NULL, CL_PLATFORM_NAME, ...)  Intel Gen OCL Driver
  clGetDeviceIDs(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, ...)   Success [Intel]
  clCreateContext(NULL, ...) [default]            Success [Intel]
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_DEFAULT)  Success (1)
    Platform Name                                 Intel Gen OCL Driver
    Device Name                                   Intel(R) HD Graphics IvyBridge M GT2
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU)  Success (1)
    Platform Name                                 Intel Gen OCL Driver
    Device Name                                   Intel(R) HD Graphics IvyBridge M GT2
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ACCELERATOR)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CUSTOM)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL)  Success (1)
    Platform Name                                 Intel Gen OCL Driver
    Device Name                                   Intel(R) HD Graphics IvyBridge M GT2

ICD loader properties
  ICD loader Name                                 OpenCL ICD Loader
  ICD loader Vendor                               OCL Icd free software
  ICD loader Version                              2.2.14
  ICD loader Profile                              OpenCL 3.0
```