# Using OpenCL with intel UHD graphics on Linux

Tags: opencv, opencl, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to use `OpenCV` with target `OpenCL` in a **Ubuntu 16.04** system with **intel UHD 620** graphics. I have installed `ocl-icd-opencl-dev` for `OpenCL` but `cv::ocl::haveOpenCL()` tells me that I do not have `OpenCL`

`clinfo` gives me

```
Number of platforms                               0
```

Then I tried installing `beignet` as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34370191/opencl-on-linux-with-integrated-intel-graphic-chip) proposes. Still `cv::ocl::haveOpenCL()` tells me that I do not have `OpenCL` and now `clinfo` says

```
Number of platforms                               1
Platform Name                                   Intel Gen OCL Driver
Platform Vendor                                 Intel
Platform Version                                OpenCL 1.2 beignet 1.1.1
Platform Profile                                FULL_PROFILE
Platform Extensions                             cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_spir cl_khr_icd
Platform Extensions function suffix             Intel
beignet-opencl-icd: no supported GPU found, this is probably the wrong opencl-icd package for this hardware
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ocl-icd-opencl-dev` are development files for OCL-ICD loader. You'll need that if you want to develop (compile) against libOpenCL. If you don't want to develop, only use OpenCL programs, then you just need `ocl-icd-libopencl1`.

> cv::ocl::haveOpenCL() tells me that I do not have OpenCL

ocl-icd is just a loader; you need an actual implementation. [As explained on Khronos:](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/specs/2.2/html/OpenCL_ICD_Installation.html)

```
The OpenCL Installable Client Driver (ICD) is a mechanism to allow OpenCL implementations from multiple vendors to coexist on a system
```

> Then I tried installing beignet

beignet is an implementation, but it's too old for your GPU. You need either their proprietary implementation, or [Intel NEO.](https://github.com/intel/compute-runtime/releases)

Comment: Thanks. I have no prior experience with `OpenCL` so I asked. I tried Intel NEO but some requirements for NEO can't be satisfied in Ubuntu 16.04. (Need 18.04 or higher for needed versions of some dependencies) By the way I no longer need OpenCL so I'm not gonna try further. Hope this answer helps someone else.